# Padding in Twitter Bootstrap

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css

I have a quick question.

How to change default padding in the text fields in Twitter Bootstrap? I am trying to set Google material one…this ones.

[image]

but I have no idea where I can change these global settings.

Answer (score 4):

NEVER change bootstraps stylesheet, doing this it makes general development a pain in the future. The best way to deal with this would be to create a new stylesheet and overwrite the styles in there (using the same bootstrap class name). Make sure that you load the new stylesheet AFTER bootstraps, that way it will override the styles.

Answer (score 0):

Don't change the default css of bootstrap framework, instead of you can take the class with same bootstrap class name or else with the bootstrap class you can use  your own class and give the css properties in new your own main style sheet which u are creating for your web page. and give the css property to that specific custom class name and if the property not apply than you can apply !important with your css property so it will work for it. (this is for related padding ans. as well as any kind of css property apply against the bootstrap default style)